# Invalid header value detected while customer password reset request

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, mageplaza

I am showing these errors in my system log while requesting a password reset, and the customer don't receive the email.

```
[2020-01-09 05:16:28] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Invalid header value detected
Trace: <pre>#1 Zend\Mail\Header\AbstractAddressList->getFieldValue(true) called at [vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Header/AbstractAddressList.php:209]
#2 Zend\Mail\Header\AbstractAddressList->toString() called at [vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Headers.php:426]
#3 Zend\Mail\Headers->toString() called at [vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Message.php:546]
#4 Zend\Mail\Message->toString() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php:217]
#5 Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage->toString() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php:209]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug of Magento version 2.3.3. It does not allow the use of special characters such as ã, ơ in-store email address or sender mail name or etc...

This is a changed path in Magento

```
vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
```

Please replace function with this code in above file :

```
public function toString(): string {
    $this->message->setEncoding('utf-8');
    return $this->message->toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm in Magento 2.3.3.

Comment: It seems that in magento 2.4 this changed, do you know what the solution for 2.4 looks like?

Comment: Yeah! also worked for me. EmailMessage.php file, line 215 in my case. Thanks all.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is a bug with encoding ...

In the EmailMessage class (vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php) the encoding can be set if passed in an argument in the constructor, but it is null by default.

```
if ($encoding) {
   $this->message->setEncoding($encoding);
}
```

So, I think the best practice use type in di.xml in your module without rewrite and plugins

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="encoding" xsi:type="string">utf-8</argument>
   </arguments>
</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the class in case some one wonders what is going on:

```
class SenderBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder
{
    /**
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException
     */
    public function send()
    {
        $this->configureEmailTemplate();
        //Removed Customer name because of diacritics
        $this->transportBuilder->addTo(
            $this->identityContainer->getCustomerEmail()
        );

        $copyTo = $this->identityContainer->getEmailCopyTo();
        if (!empty($copyTo) && $this->identityContainer->getCopyMethod() == 'bcc') {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($email);
            }
        }

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
    }
}
```